# SQL syntax for characters not in brackets

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, odbc

I'm accessing a Microsoft Access database using ODBC.

According to [the w3schools SQL tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp), the ANSI-92 wildcard for "any character not in brackets" should be `^`. However, their own example uses the ANSI-89 wildcard `!`.

The [MSDN documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b) is also confusing. The `ANSI-92` section shows `^` character, but the example next to it actually uses `!`. That looks like an error and I've filled out feedback to notify Microsoft.

What is the correct "any character not in brackets" syntax? And will this apply across multiple databases and access technologies (DAO, ODBC, OleDB, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: Nothing in that tutorial refers to the ANSI-92 standard.  That page is only discussing MS Access and SQL Server versions of `LIKE` patterns, neither of which is standard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Are you referring to the `w3schools` tutorial? At the top they show the ANSI-89 wildcards for MS Access and the immediately after the ANSI-92 wildcards for SQL Server. But their examples (and `Try It Yourself` functionality) mix the wildcard types. One example uses `[bsp]%` (ANSI-92 and standard SQL) and another uses `[!bsp]%` (mixed ANSI-89 and ANSI-92). I'm confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this across databases.  SQL supports the `LIKE` syntax that has exactly two wildcards:

- `%` matches zero or more characters.
- `_` matches exactly one character.

One could throw in the `\` character to escape wildcards as well.

In addition, SQL Server supports character classes as explained in the tutorial (which seems to be accurate).  The only other database that comes to mind that does this is Sybase (which has the same code base). MS Access just has a bastardized version with special characters.  It never supported SQL standards in this respect.

Most other databases implement full regular expression support (YAY!), but their syntax varies by database.  So, there is not a database-independent way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Already knew about the (`*`, `%`) and (`?`, `_`) wildcards. This question is specific to syntax inside brackets, which isn't directly addressed in your answer. You do answer perhaps the most important question which how to support multiple databases/database technologies. The answer is "Not easily".